# How to get all data from multiple one-to-one database relationships in Symfony?

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine

I have the following table which just keeps track of multiple one-to-one relationships. They just store integer values.

TABLE A:

```
relation_a  |  relation_b  |  relation_c
----------------------------------------
     1      |      1       |      4
```

TABLE B:

```
relation_a_ID  |  word  |  second word
--------------------------------------
     1         |  TEXT  |    FOOBAR
```

How can I retrieve this data in Symfony?

I tried doing `$tableA->findAll()`, but all I get back is an object.
How can I get the actual text and footer content ?

EIDT:

Here is my output if I get all from the content entity (where I only have
references to other one to one relation as explained)

```
dd($this->contentRepository->findAll());



 array:2 [
  0 => App\Entity\Content {#8445
    -id: 1
    -brand: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Brand {#9789
      +__isInitialized__: false
      -id: 1
      -logoThumbnail: null
      -dive: null
      -keynoteUrl: null
      -updatedAt: null
       …2
    }
    -scenario: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Scenario {#8319
      +__isInitialized__: false
      -id: 1
      -title: null
      -text: null
       …2
    }
    -example: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Example {#12653
      +__isInitialized__: false
      -id: 1
       …2
    }
    -action: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Action {#9671
      +__isInitialized__: false
      -id: 1
      -title: null
      -text: null
       …2
    }
    -consideration: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Consideration {#9760
      +__isInitialized__: false
      -id: 1
      -title: null
      -text: null
       …2
    }
  }
  1 => App\Entity\Content {#9741
    -id: 2
    -brand: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Brand {#9789 …2}
    -scenario: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Scenario {#9734
      +__isInitialized__: false
      -id: 2
      -title: null
      -text: null
       …2
    }
    -example: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Example {#9714
      +__isInitialized__: false
      -id: 2
       …2
    }
    -action: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Action {#9724
      +__isInitialized__: false
      -id: 2
      -title: null
      -text: null
       …2
    }
    -consideration: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Consideration {#9727
      +__isInitialized__: false
      -id: 2
      -title: null
      -text: null
       …2
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: What properties does the object have?

Comment: Hey I updated my question. For some reason it shows null for my content. Even tho my database is populated.

Comment: Those related entities are showing `null` values because they have not been initialized (loaded) yet. Just call getters on the `Content` entity to load related entities. `dd($this->contentRepository->findAll()[0]->getBrand());`

Comment: Hey I tried. `dd($this->contentRepository->findAll()[0]->getAction());` but for title and text I still get `null`, even tho I have 100% content  in the database. Do you need some other infos ?

Comment: And what about `dd($this->contentRepository->findAll()[0]->getAction()->getText());`?

Comment: Ah okay now I understand. Thank you. Can you post this as an answer?